# Query with Eloquent exhausts the allowed memory limit

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a really, really simple query

```
select * 
from `users` 
where (`active` = 1 and `newsletter` = 1) and (`terminated` = 0 or (`terminated` = 1 and `newsletter_terminated` = 1));
```

I'm building it with eloquent like this (The above query gets output when I make it with `toSql()`

```
$recipients = User::where([
    'active' => 1,
    'newsletter' => 1
])->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('terminated', 0)
        ->orWhere(function ($query){
            $query->where('terminated', 1)
                ->where('newsletter_terminated', 1);
        });
})->get();
```

But when I execute this script I'm getting the error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /xxx/eloquent/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 303
```

When I write specific columns in the `get` method, like `get(['id']);` it works without problems. But I still don't understand why it doesn't work otherwise. It seems that there is a memory leak, but where?

When I execute the query in my SQL client, the query gets finished withing 3 ms, so it doesn't look like there is too much data going on. Unfortunetely, I don't have xdebug on the vagrant box installed, so I can't get the stacktrace currently.

Comment: What happens when you use get(['field1', 'field2', ...]); for all columns in the table?

Comment: Sadly this returns the same error

Comment: How many records does the query return?

Comment: You can use `chunk()` method. See docs [link](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage) part **Chunking Results.**

Comment: The thing is, that I'm trying to do an CSV export, so I need all these results at once. I'm using eloquent only though, not laravel (added the tag for more views), but I can't do raw queries on Eloquent with it, right?

Answer (score 2):

Something similar happened to me. Check the $with property in your model. Maybe you have too many relationships loaded automatically. Try not to do that. Each object allocates memory. If you have 15000 rows with many relations, and you eager load each one, memory blows away. I've ended writing a raw mysql query and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems and I don't think that it's specific to Laravel -- it has to do with the embedded closures.  Basically you're overflowing 128MB for the process that interprets those closures and that may just not be enough for embedded closures.

Either try increasing your memory_limit in your php.ini (512MB should do the trick), unwrap your closures, or just use a raw SQL statement to make that query.